# How prove this inequality with peking university exam

Tags: inequality

$x,y,z\geq 0$. Let $a=x^2(y-z)^4,b=y^2(z-x)^4,a=z^2(x-y)^4$.
Prove that$\left( a+b+c \right)^3\geq \frac 9 2 \left( a\sqrt{b}+b\sqrt{c}+c\sqrt{a} \right)^2$.

This problem It is from the autumn camp of peking university, a exam today.

We can prove that if $(x-y)(z-y)\le0$ then $\sqrt[4]{b}\ge\sqrt[4]{a}+\sqrt[4]{c}$ holds,but other I can't prove it